# Configuring a Xcode project from CLI to support Apple Generic Versioning

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, fastlane

I am building an Ionic/Cordova application using fastlane. However one of the steps fails due to the fact that the default project generated by Cordova has not enabled Apple Generic Versioning for the project. I know how to enable it manually, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this from the command line.

Is it possible to set the *Current Project Version* to 1 and *Versioning System* to *Apple Generic* using the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root project folder and there is a file names `config.xml`. in the opening `<widget>` tag, update the `version="1.0.0"` to whatever you would like

Comment: This does not configure the Xcode project in the right way.